# Is there a way to find any non-trivial $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$-point on the given elliptic curve?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves, algebraic-surfaces, elliptic-surfaces

Consider a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$ (where $p \equiv 1 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 3)$, $p \equiv 3 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 4)$) and the elliptic curve
$$
E\!:y^2 = x^3 + (t^6 + 1)^2
$$
over the univariate function field $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$.

Is there a way to explicitely find any $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$-point on $E$ outside $E[3]$ (i.e., $x \neq 0$)?

Comment: Are you asking if such a point always exists? If so, the answer is no. The only points on your curve over $\mathbb{F}_{7}(t)$ and $\mathbb{F}_{19}(t)$ are those in $E[3]$ (according to analytic rank computations in Magma - in the function field case the analytic rank is known to be an upper bound for the rank).

Comment: Thank you. I thought that the most Magma functions work only with number fields (not with function fields). How are these functions called to compute the rank?

Answer (score 9):

If $2$ is a cube mod $p$ then you can take 
$(x,y) = (ct^2, t^6-1)$ where $c^3 = -4$.
This works for every odd $p \equiv -1 \bmod 3$,
but since you specified $p \equiv +1 \bmod 3$
the first case is $p=31$, with $c \in \{-3,-15,18\}$.
The next few such $p$ are $43, 127, 223, 283, 307, 439, 499, 643, 691$.
By Cubic Reciprocity, the condition on $p$ is equivalent to
$p = m^2 + 27 n^2$, and then your further requirement $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$
is equivalent to $(m,n) \equiv (0,1) \bmod 2$, e.g. $(m,n)=(2,1)$ for $p=31$.

Ultimately this works because the "potentially constant" curve $E$
is the cubic twist of $E_0: y^2 = x^3 + 1$ by $u^3 = t^6 + 1$,
and the constant curve $E_0$ is isogenous with $x^3 + y^3 = 2$.
If it were the Fermat cubic $x^3 + y^3 = 1$ then you could always do it,
but to reach $x^3 + y^3 = 2$ you need a cube root of $2$.

Comment: Thank you, but I am interested in the case when $-4$ is not cubic residue in $\mathbb{F}_p$. Is there another possible points on $E$ in this case?

Comment: You didn't impose the cubic-residue condition in your problem statement.
With that additional condition, there are no nontorsion points.
I show this by showing that the Mordell-Weil group, call it $M$,
over $\overline{{\mathbb F}_p\!}\,(t)$, has rank $6$, and
calculating the Galois action on $M \otimes {\mathbb Q}$.
If $p \equiv 7 \bmod 12$, and $2$ is not a cubic residue of $p$, then
the Galois-invariant subspace is $\{0\}$.  I'll give some more details
in a further answer.

Answer (score 9):

You can observe that the elliptic curve $E_2: y^2=x^3+(t^3+1)^2$ is a generic fibre of a rational elliptic surface. Over the algebraically closed field $k$ the group of $k(t)$ points on the curve has rank equal to 2 (by the [Shioda-Tate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/247043151_On_the_Mordell-Weil_Lattices) formula) and from the classification of possible groups of $k(t)$-rational points by [Oguiso-Shioda](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/240320684_The_Mordell-Weil_lattice_of_a_rational_elliptic_surface) (case 39 because we have three places of reduction type $IV$ away from characteristic 3) the group of $k(t)$-rational points modulo torsion has a lattice structure $A_2^{*}$. So we are looking at the points of height $1/2$ and this can be found only when one hits two singular points in the Weierstrass equation at places of bad reduction. So you obtain points of the form

$P_i=((4^{1/3}\cdot \zeta_3^i)(1 - t + t^2), \sqrt{-3}(-1 + t)(1 - t + t^2)$ for i=0,1,2

We have the relation $P_0+P_1+P_2=0$ and th points $P_1,P_2$ span a lattice of type $A_2^*$, hence are free generators.

Now you have to apply the map $t\mapsto t^2$ and on the elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+(t^6+1)^2$ you obtain two linearly independent points $P_1'$ and $P_2'$. Notice that $P_1'-P_2'$ is the negative of the point found by Noam Elkies.

The points are defined over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}(t)$. By reduction they will become naturally points over $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_{p}(t)$ and can provide points defined over $\mathbb{F}_{p}(t)$.

With a trace formula and point count (which can be done in Magma as pointed out by Jeremy Rouse in his answer) you can check that in several characteristics the rank over $\mathbb{F}_{p}(t)$ can be higher than $2$. This follows from Tate conjecture and is unconditional because the given elliptic curve is a generic fibre of a K3 surface. For example: in characteristic $p=5,11,13,17$ the rank over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ is equal to $4$.

**Addendum:**

One can play the same game with the elliptic curve $E_{tw}=E_{1}^{(t)}: y^2=x^3+(t+1)^2\cdot t^3$, which under the base change $t\mapsto t^6$ becomes isomorphic to the original curve. Curve $E_{tw}$ is a generic fibre of the rational elliptic surface with rank over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}(t)$ equal to $2$ again (now the singular fibres have different reduction type: $I_{0}^{*}$, $II$ and $IV$.). This is the case $32$ in the Oguiso-Shioda table. We find the following points of required height

$Q_{i}=(\zeta_{6}^{i}(1+t)t, \sqrt{-1}t^2(1 + t))$
for $i=1,3,5$.

There is the equality $Q_{1}+Q_{3}+Q_{5}=0$ and the points $Q_{1}$ and $Q_{3}$ are lineary independent.

Now, we base change again to the elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+(t^6+1)^2$ and obtain the following set of four linearly independent points obtained via a base change

$$\{P_{1}',P_{2}', Q_{1}',Q_{3}'\}$$

The Gram matrix is a block matrix of determinant 4.

**Second addendum:**

Finally, we consider a curve $F:y^2=x^3+(t^3-3t)^2$. It is isomorphic to $y^2=x^3+(t^6+1)^2$ under the pullback by $t\mapsto t+1/t$. Curve $F$ has three places bad reduction of type $IV$. Hence we find from the Oguiso-Shioda the points of height $1/2$. Those points are

$$R_{i}=(\zeta_{6}^{i}(t^2 - 3),\sqrt{3}(-3 + t^2))$$
for $i=1,3,5$.
We have $R_{1}+R_{3}+R_{5}$ is zero and we finally obtain the set of 6 linearly independent points
$$\{P_{1}',P_{2}', Q_{1}',Q_{3}',R_{1}',R_{3}'\}$$
which have a Gram matrix of determinant $4/3$.

The calculations above for several characteristics show that we cannot have more than 6 independent points in the group $E(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}(t))$, so up to finite index we found a basis of points. From this using the Galois action on the points you can work out the exact value of the $\mathbb{F}_{p}(t)$ rank in the cases when the Tate conjecture computation matches this bound. For the primes where the rank over $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_{p}(t)$ is higher than $6$ the extra points might exist for very peculiar reasons, e.g. the Shioda-Inose structure might throw some extra divisors into the picture and the heights of those points can be very large.

Answer (score 3):

This is too long for a comment, so I'm making it an answer. Magma now has machinery for computing ranks and generators over function fields (see [here](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/1471)) which only work for rational elliptic surfaces (using the connection with the Neron-Severi group). I used the L-function machinery (see [here](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/1473)) to compute the analytic ranks for $p = 7$, $p = 19$ and $p = 31$. One can in theory search for points the same way as one does for curves over number fields. When $p = 31$, the analytic rank is $2$ (and one generator can be found from Elkies's answer). Doing a 2-descent finds a 2-Selmer group of rank 8 (meaning there are 255 2-covers one could search for points on). The Cassels-Tate pairing is not yet implemented over function fields in Magma.