# Is there an infinite order $\mathbb{F}_{p}$-section for a certain elliptic surface $\mathcal{E}_n$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, elliptic-curves, algebraic-surfaces, elliptic-surfaces

Consider a  natural number $n$, a finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ (such that $p$ is prime, $p \equiv 1 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 3)$, $p \equiv 3 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 4)$, and $\sqrt[3]{2} \notin \mathbb{F}_p$), and the elliptic $\mathbb{F}_{p}$-surface 
$$
\mathcal{E}_n\!: y^2 = x^3 + (t^{6n} + 1)^2.
$$

[Here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/336932/is-there-a-way-to-find-any-non-trivial-mathbbf-pt-point-on-the-given-elli) I asked about infinite order $\mathbb{F}_{p}$-sections of $\mathcal{E}_1$. Is there such a section of $\mathcal{E}_n$ at least for some natural $n$? In other words, is the Mordell-Weil group of $\mathcal{E}_n$ of positive rank for some $n$?

The answer seems to be negative, but I cannot prove this. I have only confirmed my conjecture by the computer algebra system Magma for small $p$ and $n$.

Comment: I would recommend to state your question clearly here rather than to refer to your previous question. Here your notations are  different from the previous question.

Comment: You define an elliptic surface, but in order to talk about sections one needs a morphism (do you mean $(x,y,t)\mapsto t$ ?). Also, do you mean regular sections or rational sections? (I expect *rational* sections).

Comment: Yes, I mean the projection $(x,y,t) \mapsto t$ as an elliptic fibration and I would like to consider rational sections.